# Openwrt repos miss libsmpp library

Tags: openwrt, teltonika

RUTOS SDK (teltonika) requires the download of libsmpp34 from openwrt repositories, but none of them contain it.
Should I get it elsewhere ?

Traces below:

`wget --tries=5 --timeout=20 --no-check-certificate --output-document=- https://sources.cdn.openwrt.org/libsmpp34-1.14.1.tar.xz --2022-07-04 14:38:15--  https://sources.cdn.openwrt.org/libsmpp34-1.14.1.tar.xz Resolving sources.cdn.openwrt.org (sources.cdn.openwrt.org)... 151.101.122.132, 151.101.2.132, 151.101.66.132, ... Connecting to sources.cdn.openwrt.org (sources.cdn.openwrt.org)|151.101.122.132|:443... connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found 2022-07-04 14:38:16 ERROR 404: Not Found.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open /package/libs/libsmpp34/Makefile and change the line from:
PKG_SOURCE_URL=git://git.osmocom.org/libsmpp34.git

to

PKG_SOURCE_URL=https://git.osmocom.org/libsmpp34